# LUA Change Comment Style

Tags: lua, comments

Anyone know how I could change the lua comment style to `// && /* */` instead of `-- && --[[ ]]`

I would assume something such as `// = --` `/* = --[[` and `*/ = ]]` would cause problems

Anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want to build modified Lua with another comment syntax?

Comment: No, all I would like to do is add the comment syntax

Comment: Aside from the point that [`//` is already a Lua operator as of 5.3](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.1), what would be the purpose of this exercise?  It appears that you are -- perhaps without realizing it -- asking how to modify the Lua interpreter so that it can interpret code that isn't otherwise interpretable as valid Lua code.

Comment: -- Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible until you modify lua sources.

However, this makes your code unusable for everyone except you.